# Altering the Output from Hash Values in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have 2 hashes (`%hash1`, `%hash2`) with certain values in it.

I want to manipulate the hash in order to print the output in a desired way.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = (
          'Network=Europe,Node=S02,Sec=1' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S02,SecAnt=1'
                                             ],
          'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Sec=1' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S01,SecAnt=1'
                                             ],
          'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Sec=2' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S01,SecAnt=1'
                                             ]
);
my %hash2 = (
          'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Sec=2' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=1'
                                             ],
          'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Sec=1' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=3'
                                             ],
          'Network=Europe,Node=S02,Sec=1' => [
                                               'Network=Europe,Node=S02,Cell=1'
                                             ]
);

my %altered;

foreach my $sec (keys %hash1){
    foreach my $ant (@{$hash1{$sec}}) {
        push @{$altered{$ant}},$hash2{$sec};
    }
}

my $i = 0;

foreach my $sec_ant (sort keys %altered){
    ++$i;
    print "sec_ant_$i:$sec_ant\n";
    foreach my $val (@{$altered{$sec_ant}}){
        foreach my $cell (@$val){
            print "cell_$i:$cell\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Present output:

```
sec_ant_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,SecAnt=1
cell_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=1
cell_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=3
sec_ant_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,SecAnt=1
cell_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,Cell=1
```

Expected/Desired Output:

```
sec_ant_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,SecAnt=1
cell_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=1###Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=3
sec_ant_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,SecAnt=1
cell_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,Cell=1
```

If the particular `sec_ant_x` have multiple `cell_x` values, it should concatenate it with the `###` delimeter.  Also, the `cell_x` values should be unique. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the way you create your `altered` data structure; I dereference the array before storing it.  This simplifies retrieval.

Then you can [join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join) the elements of the array with `###` when you print:

```
my %altered;

foreach my $sec (keys %hash1){
    foreach my $ant (@{$hash1{$sec}}) {
        push @{$altered{$ant}}, @{$hash2{$sec}};
    }
}

my $i = 0;

foreach my $sec_ant (sort keys %altered){
    ++$i;
    print "sec_ant_$i:$sec_ant\n";
    print "cell_$i:", join('###', @{$altered{$sec_ant}}), "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
sec_ant_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,SecAnt=1
cell_1:Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=1###Network=Europe,Node=S01,Cell=3
sec_ant_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,SecAnt=1
cell_2:Network=Europe,Node=S02,Cell=1
```

Comment: One small correction (I haven't mentioned in my example this scenario, sorry for that). Since I need unique cell values, I have used module `List::MoreUtils`'s `uniq` function. The print statement is like this - `print "cell_$i:", join('###', uniq @{$altered{$sec_ant}}), "\n";`